# Can't convert a Number to String using $toString

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm studying MongoDB (version 4.0.0) aggregate feature but I can't make a simple $toString to work fine. When I remove the $toString operator I get the following output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4fa13c0ec5e844757333d5"), "payment_date" : 20180621, "payment_date_formatted" : 20180721 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4fa13c0ec5e844757333d7"), "payment_date" : 20180626, "payment_date_formatted" : 20180726 }
```

But when I try to convert the field `payment_date_formatted`, everything goes wrong and the output is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4fa13c0ec5e844757333d5"), "payment_date" : 20180621, "payment_date_formatted" : "2.01807e+07" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4fa13c0ec5e844757333d7"), "payment_date" : 20180626, "payment_date_formatted" : "2.01807e+07" }
```

Why this is happening? This is the aggregate call:

```
db.payment_orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "company": ObjectId("5b368de558b52c13789edddd"),
      "payment_date": {
        "$gte": 20170601
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "payment_date_formatted": {
        "$add": [
          "$payment_date",
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "payment_date": 1,
      "payment_date_formatted": {$toString: "$payment_date_formatted"}
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Use `$toLong` aggregation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) and [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation simultaneously here

```
db.payment_orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "payment_date": { "$toLong": "$payment_date" },
      "payment_date_formatted": {
        "$toString": { "$toLong": "$payment_date_formatted" }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2e7SQYIAhpB)